# NodeJs Error: spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe; ENOENT

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, cmd, child-process

This is my script :

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

    exec('dir', function(error, stdout, stderr) {  // 'dir' is for example
      if (error) {
        console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
        return;
      }
      console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
      console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
    });
```

And in the console I have :

```
exec error: Error: spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe; ENOENT
```

Someone can help me ?

Comment: Sounds to me like Node doesn't have a PATH or doesn't have permission to run `cmd.exe`. It's trying to run `cmd.exe` for you (because you gave a built-in, `dir`, and it's smart like that), but it can't find it (either because it really isn't there, or that's what the OS told it when denying access).

Comment: Thanks a lot @T.J.Crowder, I'm going to continue to search with your advice :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have this also :
{ [Error: spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe; ENOENT]
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe;',
  path: 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe;',
  spawnargs: [ '/s', '/c', '"dir"' ],
  cmd: 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe; /s /c "dir"' }

You see other thing ?

Comment: I found a fix see my answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40798047/uncaught-error-spawn-node-exe-enoent/45275282#45275282

Comment: on windows 7 installing installing window build tools fixed the issue, https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools#examples-of-modules-supported

Answer (score 18):

This can also be caused if you are feeding in ExecOptions the options parameter, specifically 'cwd', and the path you provide is invalid

e.g:

```
cp.exec(<path_to_executable>, {
  cwd: <path_to_desired_working_dir>
}, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  //......
})
```

If  is not valid, the callback will be called with err equal to

> Error: spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe ENOENT

Comment: This solved it for me, thank you so much

Answer (score 10):

I got to resolve the issue the problem is to remove the semicolon(;) from an end of the 
ComSpec path C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe

Mycomputer>properties>Advance System Settings>Environment Variables>System Variables

add this path:
[image]ComSpec C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was that my solution directory was on a different drive than windows. Creating my solution on my C drive solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the maxBuffer solved the problem for me.

```js
const child_process = require('child_process');

var command = 'git ls-files . --ignored --exclude-standard --others';

child_process.execSync(command, {
   maxBuffer: 1024 ** 6,
});
```