# Uncaught Error: spawn .\node.exe ENOENT

Tags: node.js, express, electron, spawn

I have a nodejs app being run through electron

https://github.com/frankhale/electron-with-express

After packaging the app as an executable using `npm run dist:win32`, I ran into the following issue in console:

```
events.js:160 Uncaught Error: spawn .\node.exe ENOENT
```

Below is how my devDependencies looks like

```
"devDependencies": {
    "electron-builder": "^5.26.0",
    "electron-prebuilt": "^1.3.3",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.2.0"
  }
```

When i run the app using npm start it works fine, and no error is run. Its when the app is run as an executable i see the error on console.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, after many try/search, I found a solution. Use 'fix-path'.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/fix-path

`npm install --save fix-path`

Then, use it like this before your spawn :

```
// Use to access 'spawn' when the app is packaged
const fixPath = require('fix-path')();
// or
const fixPath = require('fix-path');
fixPath();
```

Comment: Work like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

low rep here or else I would just comment. Thanks for sharing your repo. I used a combo of your solution and [this workaround](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2708) to get processes spawned from inside packaged .app.